# Error in opening image file in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to execute the following code

```
from pytesser import *
import Image

i="C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/attachments/R1PNDTCB.jpg"
print i
im = Image.open(i.strip())
text = image_to_string(im)
print text
```

I get the following error

```
C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/attachments/R1PNDTCB.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 322, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 655, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\attachments\ocr.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pytesser import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1952, in open
    fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/attachments/R1PNDTCB.jpg'
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here.

Renamed the image file.Shifted the python file and the images to a new folder. Shifted the folder to E drive
Now the code is as follows:

```
from pytesser import *
import Image
import os

i=os.path.join("E:\\","ocr","a.jpg")
print i
im = Image.open(i.strip())
text = image_to_string(im)
print text
```

Now the error is as follows:

```
E:\ocr\a.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "or.py", line 8, in <module>
    text = image_to_string(im)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pytesser.py", line 31, in image_to_string
    call_tesseract(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pytesser.py", line 21, in call_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Make sure you have the path right. `from os.path import isfile; assert isfile(i))` where you currently have `print i`.

Comment: Does that file currently exist at that location?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install Tesseract first. Just installing pytesseract is not enough. Then edit the tesseract_cmd variable in pytesseract.py to point the the tessseract binary. For example, in my installation I set it to

```
tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
```

Comment: there is no tesseracr_cmd variable in my pytesser.py , How do I rectify this mistake ?

Answer (score 3):

The exception is pretty clear: the file either doesn't exist, or you lack sufficient permissions to access it. If neither is the case, please provide evidence (e.g. relevant `dir` commands with output, run as the same user).

Comment: I'm betting on permissions, since they're trying to access something owned by Administrator.

Comment: @Jonah, I'm changing my mind - that path doesn't look correct. Navigate to the file in Windows Explorer and copy/paste the path from the location dropdown at the top.

Comment: does pytesser need to be given any permissions?

Answer (score 0):

your image path maybe?

```
i="C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\attachments\\R1PNDTCB.jpg"
```

try this:

```
import os
os.path.join("C:\\", "Documents and Settings", "Administrator")
```

you should get a string similar to the one in the previous line

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:

`os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/attachments/R1PNDTCB.jpg')`

It could be that the space in the 'Documents and Settings' is causing this problem.

EDIT:

Use `os.path.join` so it uses the correct directory separator.

Comment: I tried changing the directory to D it gives the following error `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Windows is able to use `'/'` and `'\\'` interchangeably, so the separator isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two lines in your code

import **OS**

```
os.chdir('C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pytesser')
```

before

```
from pytesser import *
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pytesseract, you have to make sure that you have installed Tesseract-OCR in your system. After that you have to insert the path of the tesseract in your code, as below

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract 
OCR/tesseract'
```

You can download the Tesseract-OCR form https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki