# Python : Gives [Errno 2] No such file or directory on openshift

Tags: python, python-2.7, openshift

I am using python-flask and deploying my app on openshift. App url is [this](http://fypfinal-searchall.rhcloud.com/).

I am uploading an image and with the help of pytesseract lib, then extracting the text from that uploaded image.

So far here is the code what I have written:

```
    path = os.path.join(os.getenv('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'),'yi.jpg')
    with open(path,'w') as f:
        f.write(resp.content)
    try:
        import Image
    except ImportError: 
        from PIL import Image
    import pytesseract
    #return path gives var/lib/openshift/56faaee42d527151d5000089/app-root/data/yi.jpg
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(path))
    return text
```

If I return the `path` variable then its value is `var/lib/openshift/56faaee42d527151d5000089/app-root/data/yi.jpg` and when I login through ssh and route to this location I see a file present in that location.

> Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

File "pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 132, in image_to_string
boxes=boxes)

File "pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 73, in run_tesseract
  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But why compiler is complaining on no such file or dir.

Comment: Your path doesn't have a leading slash (i.e. `var/lib/...` instead of `/var/lib/...`.  This seems odd, but it obviously works for the `with open` statement.

Comment: @JohnGordon, looks like an answer

Comment: @JohnGordon so where should I change the code ?

Comment: @SurajPalwe, OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR env var must be wrong...check it's definition in your system.

Comment: @SurajPalwe, did you set  `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`?

Comment: Try changing the value of the `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` environment variable to include the leading slash.  This wouldn't be a code change; it's probably set in your `.bashrc` or other similar file.

Comment: Still, though, the file path obviously worked for writing the file; why wouldn't it work for reading?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No I didn't set `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` var

Comment: @SurajPalwe, what does `echo $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't know about `bash` so I login trough `ssh` and run the above command, which gave me `OPENSHIFT`

Comment: Run `cat ~/.bashrc | grep OPENSHIFT`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham output of above command is No such file or directory

Comment: For now to at least see if it works add a `"/" + path` and try the code again, if that works we can worry about finding where it is set

Comment: @PadraicCunningham after reading first comment I tried but gives me same error

Comment: Can you add the full traceback

Comment: I see that you're on the way to the traceback, just a point in passing by...  Would it work without using `os.path.join`? The `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` actually should contain the leading slash, so I would try `path = os.getenv('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR') + '/yi.jpg'` to create the `path` string.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry I took time to add traceback. I have updated the question and added traceback

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that Tesseract is installed on the server ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788623/1791201)).

Having the Python module is not enough, as it then calls the binary.