# pytesser, PIL : IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ovh, pytesser

I'm trying to use pytesser but i have an error at the last line :

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

My code is `Python 2.7 version` :

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image

import os   

from pytesseract import *
from pytesser import *

file = "fonts_test.png";
img = Image.open( file )
img.load()
print( image_to_string( img ) )
```

However `fonts_test.png` exists in the same directory than my code.
It is an internal problem in `pytesser` or `PIL` ?

I use this code on my `OVH` shared server. I installed `pytesser` in the same directory than my code. `OVH`manage `PIL`

Thanks !

Comment: `Image` is imported from `PIL`  then it's problem with `PIL` only.

Comment: If I recall correctly, both libraries simply call tessaract binary with correct arguments. Does your OS have tesseract binary installed and is it in path (is it runnable without specifying full path to binary)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587454/error-in-opening-image-file-in-pil try this

Comment: _I use this code on my OVH shared server_ so you **do not** have tesseract installed on this machine. `pytesser` does not perform OCR, it simply dispatches input image to tesseract binary, retrieves recognition data and returns it to caller.